# WPF - datagrid adorner not updating upon binded PropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged, adorner

I am using a solution found here:  http://malor.se/blog/?p=88 to add adorners to a datagrid text column.  Works fine, except my adorner is binded to the underlying object, and it's failing to update upon source property changes.  I can even bind the cell contents and the adorner text to the same property, and the cell content will reflect property changes while the adorner text doesn't.  The adorner seems to refresh only when I do something to force a redraw of the cell, like resizing the column.

Is there a fairly non-hackish way I can get the adorner to refresh upon source property changes like other normal wpf controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web searching seems to indicate that the adorner layer refreshes only on certain events, like a resizing, for the sake of performance I suppose.  I'm now of the opinion that maybe it's not the best choice for my particular task.